# resource distribution over a cluster

Tags: algorithm, resources, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

The beginning is pretty standard. Suppose you have a limited number of resources. Each resource has its own dynamically changing weight. Also you have nodes which could disappear and appear back. So the goal is to distribute these resources over the nodes.

Key points:

1. Distribute resources in most evenly way or close to it
2. Minimize resource movements

Could you advise articles on the topic?

Comment: You could suggest an algorithm or better it's immplementation? Obviously I've tried search engines, but didn't find anything interesting so far. I thought that SO is place where you can be guided in interesting questions. Not only bugs in hello world programs.